# file_get_contents() suddenly started to throw an 'Invalid IP' error

Tags: php, ip, file-get-contents

For several years I used `file_get_contents()` like this forcing it to use IPv4:

```
file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create([
    'socket' => ['bindto' => '0:0']
]));
```

Though the function seems to keep working, a few months ago it started to throw the following error:

> file_get_contents(): Invalid IP Address: 0

How can I fix this?

P.S. I noticed that when the wrapper function of `file_get_contents()` is called from `__construct` of a triggered `ErrorHandler`, no errors is thrown. So strange.

Comment: Just as a note, using [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) might be a better way of getting the contents, as it's a lot more robust than `file_get_contents`

Comment: @aynber I use file_get_contents() when curl fails